# Onclick alert works even if the form is empty? and after clicking on submit button alert shows 1st then it shows that the input field is required

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, onclick, form-submit

Here's my code. Now here what happens is when I fill that specific form with just 1 input the data gets submitted and the alert is shown after that, but if I don't fill anything in the form and just click on submit button, the alert is shown even if the form is empty, and after the alert, it shows that please fill out this field.. so what went wrong? tried searching for this solution and tried so many things but nothing works... :(

```
<div class="newsletter">
    <p>Sign Up for the <strong>NEWSLETTER</strong></p>
        <form method="post">
              <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['subscribe']))
                    {
                       $e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];

                       $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','purrfect_whiskers');
                       if($conn->connect_error)
                       {
                           echo "$conn->connect_error";
                           die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
                       } 
                        else 
                        {
                          $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into newsletter(e_mail) values(?)");
                          $stmt->bind_param("s", $e_mail);
                          $stmt->execute();

                          $stmt->close();
                          $conn->close();
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            <input class="input" type="email" name="e_mail" text-transform="lowercase" placeholder="Enter Your Email" autocomplete="off" required="required">
            <button class="subscribe" onclick="submit_email()" type="submit" name="subscribe"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Subscribe</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">function submit_email(){alert("You've been subscribed to our newsletter!");}</script>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an `onclick` event handler to show that alert. The `onclick` fires will be executed as soon as someone clicks the button. That is _before_ the form is submitted to the server, so by the time of showing that alert, the user is not actually subscribed yet. I'd add a message to the page thanking them, inside of the `if(isset($_POST['subscribe']))` branch. And use an else to show the form, so they can't enter the form again. Or redirect to another "thank you" page, so that even refreshing the page doesn't submit your data again.

Comment: yes, i removed the onclick function and added onsubmit instead of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should validate that the user did put in a value for email before allowing the submission. If they did not, present an error. If they did, allow the submission and on page refresh, present the success alert

There are a couple ways to prevent automatic form submission, one of them is to put an `onsubmit` handler in the `form` tag and have it return `true` (to allow the submission or `false` to prevent it. You can do all your validating in that handler:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return submit_email()">
```

Then in your function, check that the value is there before allowing it to continue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function submit_email(){
    let email_input = document.querySelector("input[name='e_mail']");
    if (email_input.value=="") {
      alert("Please type in your email first");
      return false; // this prevents the form from submitting
    }
    return true; // this allows the submission
  }
</script>
```

The form will submit, the page will refresh and your PHP code will do it's thing. At the end of which, just hardcode your alert, like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['subscribe'])){
 // do all your code as you are, then end with:
?>

<script>
    alert("You've been subscribed to our newsletter!");
</script>

<?php                    
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't need that function at all if you use the built-in `required` validation constraint.

Comment: @lvar - good point. Though the walk-through on the submission cycle of form events was needed here - like there might be a need to check to see if that email address already exists before allowing submission...

Answer (score 0):

The alert code executes no matter what. You must therefore display it only if there is nothing in your form.
For that, I added an id in your input and I made a check to know if your form is empty or not.
The best would be to check with regex if it is indeed an email address but here is the code just to verify if it is just not empty
Here is the code:

```
<div class="newsletter">
    <p>Sign Up for the <strong>NEWSLETTER</strong></p>
    <form method="post">
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['subscribe'])) {
           $e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
           $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','purrfect_whiskers');
           if($conn->connect_error) {
             echo "$conn->connect_error";
             die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
           } else {
             $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into newsletter(e_mail) values(?)");
             $stmt->bind_param("s", $e_mail);
             $stmt->execute();
             $stmt->close();
             $conn->close();
           }
        }
        ?>
        <input id="id_input" class="input" type="email" name="e_mail" text-transform="lowercase"
               placeholder="Enter Your Email"
               autocomplete="off" required="required">
        <button class="subscribe" onclick="submit_email()" type="submit" name="subscribe"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            Subscribe
        </button>
        <script type="text/javascript">function submit_email() {
            if (document.getElementById("id_input").value !== "") {
                alert("You've been subscribed to our newsletter!");
            }
        }</script>
    </form>
</div>
```